# SEO benefits of linking directly to a scientific paper opposed to linking through a more stable digital object Identifier (DOI) redirect

Tags: seo, redirects, links

Different sources show that the type of outgoing links on a site have a minor effect on its ranking (https://searchenginewatch.com/2016/11/02/guide-to-google-ranking-factors-part-9-outbound-links/).

Assuming that this is correct, lets say that linking to a relevant scientific paper, hosted on the site of a reputable scientific press, creates a minor ranking bonus for your own site.

**The question is:**

Is there a difference between linking the paper directly: https://www.nature.com/nrc/journal/v17/n7/full/nrc.2017.47.html

As opposed to linking via its DOI, which redirects to the paper: https://doi.org/10.1038/nrc.2017.47

(A Digital Object Identifier is a stable URL redirect).

Comment: doi.org uses "303 See Other" redirects.    That may effect whether or not you get SEO credit.  It would be more straightforward if they used "301 Permantent" redirects.

Comment: The 303 would definitely be detrimental if you're redirecting from one of your pages to the other. In this case, the academic site won't get the link juice. I don't think it affects the site that's linking out, though. There is definitely not enough research in the area...

Answer (score 2):

For SEO purposes, either one is going to be fine.

1. Crawlers will still follow the link and hit the correct article, so you're not doing anything illegal.
2. Search engine engineers are no doubt aware of the DOI standard. And because it's used primarily in academia - and search engines like good academic content - it's highly unlikely they'd penalize you for using it.
3. If this were a known SEO issue, you'd hear about it immediately, and there'd be a lot of research on this topic.

Just make sure your anchor text is properly descriptive.